# Performance of @XmlSeeAlso

Tags: java, jaxb, jersey

This is related to this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21486734/jaxb-jersey-how-return-a-generic-dto-that-contains-a-list

Basically, I am wondering what are the performance implications of @XmlSeeAlso if I annotate a class like so.

So a PagedResultListDTO will only ever contain one type of class, but I have to annotate it will all the classes that it may possibly hold, will this impact performance? (the alternative is to create X wrapper classes for each separate DTO class rather than the generic wrapper below)

```
@XmlSeeAlso({TeamDTO.class, UserDTO.class, etc etc})
public class PagedResultListDTO<E> {

  private List<E> results;
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Each class that your `JAXBContext` is aware of will be processed and have metadata created for it.  If you have one root class and N value classs then metadata will be created N + 1 times.  If you create a root class for each value class then metadata will be created 2N times.

A `JAXBContext` is a thread-safe object so your framework should not be recreating them.